# upload a file thorugh request.session is not working in python

Tags: python, request

i am trying to pass a file in a post call in python using request.session ,

```
    self.session = requests.Session()
    self.session.auth = (username, password)
    self.session.verify = False
    self.session.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json'
    self.session.headers['Content-Type'] = 'multipart/form-data'
    files = {'file': open('myfile.json', 'rb')}
    resp = self.session.post(self.url, files = files)
```

but it does not work i gives error

**type** Status report

**message** Bad Request

**description** The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.

Comment: Try to exclude `'Content-Type'` from `headers`

Comment: it does not work , i get 404